# How to run shell scripts on IronWorker?

Tags: iron.io, ironworker

How do I run shell scripts on IronWorker? It would only perform a simple Curl inside the worker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

curl.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

curl http://www.google.com
```

curl.worker

```
runtime "binary"
exec "curl.sh"
```